# What does the "AS DBO" part of a GRANT do?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given...

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[SomeSproc] TO [Some_User] AS [dbo]
```

What EXACTLY does the "AS DBO" part do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just controls who (dbo) is recorded as having issued the GRANT.  See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

The grantor (or the principal specified with the AS option) must have either the permission itself with GRANT OPTION, or a higher permission that implies the permission being granted.

The dbo, or database owner, is a user account that has implied permissions to perform all activities in the database.

[image]
[image]

Read more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669065(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

dbo is the user in database. It is known as database owner. You are running a grand command as database owner

For more: - http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server